# segmentation fault when calling c function on ruby

Tags: c, ruby, segmentation-fault

I am trying to extends my Ruby code with a C functions. The C code compiles without warning. But When I try to run the ruby code, I got a segmentation fault:

I have this c code:

```
#include <ruby.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "nessie.h"

/* #define TRACE_INTERMEDIATE_VALUES */

/*
 * The number of rounds of the internal dedicated block cipher.
 */
#define R 10

VALUE rb_mExample;
VALUE rb_cClass;

// ...

static char* displayHash(const unsigned char array[], int length){
  int i, k;
  char *str;

  str = malloc(3 * length + 1);
  if (str == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  k = 0;
  str[0] = '\0';
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
    char hex[3];

    if (i % 32 == 0){
      str[k++] = ' ';
    }

    if (i % 8 == 0){
      str[k++] = ' ';
    }
    snprintf(hex, sizeof(hex), "%02X", array[i]);

    str[k++] = hex[0];
    str[k++] = hex[1];
  }

  str[k] = '\0';

  return str;
}


VALUE
print_string(VALUE class, VALUE *valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];

  int i;
  for (i = 0; valor[i] != '\0'; i++);
  int sizeo = i;

  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)valor, 8*sizeo, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);

  return (VALUE) displayHash(digest, DIGESTBYTES);
}

void
Init_example(){
  rb_mExample = rb_define_module("Example");
  rb_cClass = rb_define_class_under(rb_mExample, "Class", rb_cObject);

  rb_define_method(rb_cClass, "print_string", print_string, 1);
}
```

and this Ruby code:

```
require "example"

def print
  e = Example::Class.new
  e.print_string("ruby")
end
```

When I run the ruby code, I got a segmentation fault.

EDIT: gist with log info

https://gist.github.com/psantos10/f07484afa26ce0e55181

Where I failing? I am new in C language.

EDIT:

I changed my "print_string" to look like this:

```
VALUE
print_string(VALUE class, VALUE *valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];

  int i;
  for (i = 0; valor[i] != '\0'; i++);
  int sizeo = i;

  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)valor, 8*sizeo, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);

  return rb_str_new(displayHash(digest, DIGESTBYTES), 128);
}
```

whith that, segmentation fault gone. But the string returned is coming with a strange characters like:

> "ruby\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00No error detected.\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD80x\xC0\x18`\x18\x18&F\xAF\x05#\x8C##\xB8\x91\xF9~\xC6?\xC6\xC6\xFB\xCDo\x13\xE8\x87\xE8\xE8\xCB\x13\xA1L\x87&\x87\x87\x11mb\xA9\xB8\xDA\xB8\xB8\t\x02\x05\b\x01\x04\x01\x01\r\x9EnBO!OO\x9Bl\xEE\xAD6\xD866\xFFQ\x04Y\xA6\xA2\xA6\xA6\f\xB9\xBD\xDE\xD2o\xD2"

When the correct must be only:

> "ruby"

### EDIT 3:

Making this change:

```
VALUE
print_string(VALUE class, VALUE *valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];
 /*
  int i;
  for (i = 0; valor[i] != '\0'; i++);
  int sizeo = i;
 */
  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)"ruby", 8*4, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);

  return rb_str_new(displayHash(digest, DIGESTBYTES), 128);
}
```

the correct value are returned.

Then I try to to that:

```
VALUE
print_string(VALUE class, VALUE *valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];
 /*
  int i;
  for (i = 0; valor[i] != '\0'; i++);
  int sizeo = i;
 */
  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)"ruby", 8*4, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);

  return rb_str_new2(valor);
}
```

Expecting "ruby" string to be returned. But not. It returns: "\x05"

What that mean?

Comment: You can't just cast c strings to/from VALUE - you need to use the appropriate conversion functions - see http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/README_EXT.html

Comment: @FrederickCheung using "rb_str_new" as the documents says, I can now return a string. But strange characters are appended.

See my EDIT please

Comment: You've passed 128 as the last parameter to rb_str_new so you'll get back something 128 bytes long

Comment: @FrederickCheung please see my edit #3

Comment: you need to pass a c string to rb_str_new_2 - you're passing a ruby object (See StringValuePtr, StringValueCStr etc)

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I changed the params to "char *valor" and "char* valor" same thing happened

Comment: Just changing the function signature doesn't changed the data you're passed

Comment: It's Works now! I will post the correct code. Thanks for your help

@FrederickCheung if you know what I am dealing with, you can see: https://github.com/AngoDev/kryptonita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before all, let me thanks @FrederickCheung for give me the right direction.

The solution code is:

```
VALUE
print_string(VALUE class, VALUE valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];
  VALUE info;

  // Note here I must convert the Ruby VALUE type to C type. Thats is the trick. 
  char* valor2 = RSTRING_PTR(valor);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; valor2[i] != '\0'; i++);
  int sizeo = i;

  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)valor2, 8*sizeo, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);

  info = rb_str_new_cstr(displayHash(digest, DIGESTBYTES));

  return info;
}
```

For who want to see where this code was used, can access: https://github.com/AngoDev/kryptonita

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Inside this loop for each passing if condition you increment `k` so by doing this you will be having array out of bound access hence the crash.

Make sure the

```
char *str = malloc( 3 * length + 1);
```

is not

```
char *str = malloc( 3 * (length + 1));
```

For Eg:

Have value of `length = 2;`

```
char *str = malloc(7);
```

Now in the for loop you increment `k` 4 times.

```
k = 4;
```

Now after the second iteration if you exit the loop then

```
k=8;
```

So `str[8]` is not a valid access and might lead to crash

Comment: but this code, if I return a char * , and test it on C its works. only when I return a VALUE type this error occurs